# How to create Dynamic Create Forms on a Single Page in Oracle Adf 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jdeveloper

My requirement is:

I have two `jspx pages` namely, `view1.jspx` and `view2.jspx`.
I have two hyperlinks in the `view1.jspx` page namely `Add Name Details` and `Add Address Details`.
When clicking `Add Name Details`, control should go to the `view2.jspx` with a Create Form to the table named `NameData` where I have three columns, `"Name", "Sex" and "Date of Birth"`.
The form should contain components as InputText, Radio button Calendar respectively
Now, when clicking the second hyperlink `Add Address Details`,control should go to the same page`view2.jspx` with a different form for the `AddressData` table with three other different columns `"City", "Country" and "PIN Code"`.Where the components here would be drop down, drop down and an Input Text.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switcher component to switch what is shown on the page.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMuZJvU5eTk